# .NetCore Swagger can not work

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I took long time to try to configure swagger for my .netCore project.

the following steps I have done, but not successful :-(

1. Nuget Package:

   ```
   Swashbuckler.SwaggerGen,
   Swashbuckler.SwaggerUi,
   ```
2. in ConfigureServices Method

   ```
   instance.AddMvc();
   instance.AddSwaggerGen();
   ```
3. in Config Method

   ```
    instance.UseMvc();
    instance.UseSwagger();
    instance.UseSwaggerUi();
   ```
4. I rebuild my project, and go to link http://localhost:5000/swagger/ui

came error: localhost refused to connect.ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can anybody help me??

BR,

Leon

Comment: Is your application even running on this port? when you run with a newly created project it runs on IIS Express, usually with high random seeming number like 45342

Comment: Hi Tseng, yes my allication is running on 5000

Comment: Then you shouldn't get connection refused messages and get 200 (all okay), 404 (page not found) or 500 (internal server error, i.e. an exception)

Comment: Hi Tseng, Do you know, how can I set a port for swagger?

Comment: You don't. It will be running on the same application. Are you absolutely positively sure that you can reach your application at http://localhost:5000? If you can, then you should'n get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. In all likeliness you would get a 404 at /swagger/ui. Have you tried removing the /ui part?

Comment: Hi Marcus W, yes, I sure, I can reach my application at localhost:5000

Comment: Please refer the below link. This worked for me too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629590/2367302

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have in my aspnet core rest api project.

In `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
        Title = "MyProject - HTTP API",
        Version = "v1",
        Description = "My project HTTP API."
    });
});
```

In the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyProj HTTP API v1");
});
```

Then simply navigate to `http://localhost:56468/swagger/` where `56468` is the port my application is running on.

Comment: Hi, now it works fine, but the other error is: Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json.

Comment: Could you update your question with exactly how your code looks now?

Answer (score 0):

You should include NuGet package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` for swagger configuration. Add below code in `Configure` section of Startup.cs

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

And add below code in `ConfigureServices` section of Statup

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
       c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo() { Title = "My API", Description = "My API V1" });
    });
```