# Swagger Page is 404 Not Found in MVC net-core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I have a brand new .NET-Core Web API project that I want to use API versioning and swagger.

When I try to view the swagger page I get a 404. However, the default ValuesController that comes with the template works.

Here is my setup:

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // Add API Versioning
        services.AddApiVersioning(
            options =>
            {
                options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            });

        // Add Swagger
        string pathToDoc = "RegistriesApi.xml";
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                new Info
                {
                    Title = "Registries API",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "A simple api to interact with AMA registries information",
                    TermsOfService = "None"
                });

            string filePath = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, pathToDoc);
            options.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
            options.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
        });
    }
    ...
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Url Path Rewriter
        RewriteOptions rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            rewriteOptions.AddRedirectToHttps();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);

        // Use MVC
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // Swagger
        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) => swagger.Host = httpReq.Host.Value);
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(
            c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs"); });
    }
```

ValuesController.cs

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new[] {"value1", "value2"};
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Also, here is the version for all the libraries I have installed:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the *XML documentation file* option in the *Output* section on the *Build* tab of the project properties?

Comment: @R.Richards Yes, I forgot to include that in my question. The XML document is getting generated correctly, but still getting the 404

Comment: try to put swagger before `.UseMvc`

Comment: @Set Tried that, still getting a 404

Comment: Try setting up the root url for swagger

Comment: Did that as well. I'll update with the actual fix ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I created the project, I accidentally included the .vs folder in check in. When I removed it from source control, for whatever reason swagger started working again.

Not sure that the explanation is for this.

Comment: Mine randomly started working again when I deleted the .vs file from the solution in explorer. Although it didn't help that I was getting an error from one of my controllers... I think that may have been the issue...

Comment: Mine as well, it simply started working after deleting the .vs folder.  This was driving me crazy.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped a lot
Every time i set up a project there is something different with the swagger UI

Comment: Just ran into this now. Was working perfectly, then all of a sudden it gave 404. Closed VS2017 and removed /.vs folder. Now it works again.

Comment: I have run into the same issue with VS 2019. Deleting .vs folder resolves the issue. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 2):

The combination from above answers worked for me:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Name of Your API v1");
});
```

Comment: With `c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` the URL is /index.html otherwise it is /swagger/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted the `.vs` folder in the solution's root directory.  Now it works...

Comment: Still valid with .net framework 4.8, VStudio 2022 - May 2023.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem after discovered that by error I forgot to add to the startup.cs file (or the equivalent that you are using for startup.cs in NET 6.0)

In the method Configure Add:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
     endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me after migrating from `.NET 5` to `.NET 6`

Answer (score 0):

For me @Tyler Findlay solution didn't work out. But I did it in a different way that works fine for me.

1. Recreate the project, ensure the checkbox Configure for HTTPS checked if API needs to be secured, based on this option some of the code of line will be added into startup.cs
2. Install the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger through Nuget.
3. Install the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen & Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI through Nuget. Remember the AspNetCore.Swagger internally install the SwaggerGen and UI, but you can add it through Nuget.
4. Compile the Project and Run it.

Hope this will help somebody.

Update: the URL can be HTTP://localhost:/swagger/ui

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, check your Configure() method in Startup.cs, you should add these lines if they are not present:

```
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Name of Your API v1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this problem by adding the following code `c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` in `app.UseSwaggerUI`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I defined Authentication and Authorization with `builder.Services.AddAuthentication`, `builder.Services.AddAuthorization`, but forgot to add the usage of it `app.UseAuthentication()`, `app.UseAuthorization()`.